# What is the functionality of this code?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can anyone help me with this program in LISP:

```
(defun callie(x y) (if x (callie (cdr x) y))
    (if (= (mod (car x) y) 0) (format t "~a~%" (car x))))
```

I have to understand the functionality and repair it. What does this program do?

Comment: Homework? If so, tag it as such.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to understand that program, you should probably start by fixing the formatting:

```
(defun callie (x y)
  (if x
      (callie (cdr x) y))
  (if (= (mod (car x) y) 0)
      (format t "~a~%" (car x))))
```

Replacing `if`s without a else-branch with `when`s, and the comparison with 0 with the specific `zerop` predicate, can further clarify things:

```
(defun callie (x y)
  (when x
    (callie (cdr x) y))
  (when (zerop (mod (car x) y))
    (format t "~a~%" (car x))))
```

The expected parameter types seem to be a list of integers for x, and an integer for y. The purpose of the function seems to be to print all elements of x that are multiples of y.

A problem seems to be that the function recurses until `x` is empty, and then tries to do the check on the first element of that version of `x` (which obviously doesn't exist). So, to fix this, you would have to make sure that the function won't try to process the empty list further. The preferable approach, in my opinion, would be to make use of a standard function or macro for processing a list for side-effects, like `mapc` or `dolist`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code tries to print all possible values from the list X where the value is exact-divisible by Y.

It has some errors in it, though.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to write that in Common Lisp is to use a function which returns a new list, where all items, which don't divide to zero with the given number, are removed.

Typically this test is written as a predicate function which returns a boolean. This functions then is used to remove the unwanted items from the list.

See REMOVE-IF and REMOVE-IF-NOT.

Your task is to get the recursion right. But in real Lisp code, the recursion is not used directly.